# $\phi: G\to G$ is a homomorphism. Denote $Ker \phi := K$ and $ Im\phi := H$. If $K \cap H =\{e\}$, can we say that $G=KH$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

While solving a problem, I came across the following question :

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Suppose $\phi: G\to G$ be a homomorphism. Denote $Ker \phi := K$ and $ Im\phi := H$. If  $K \cap H =\{e\}$, can we say that $G=KH$ ?

Thanks for your comments/answers in advance.

Comment: Suppose $g\in G$ and $\phi(g) = h$. Can you find an element $k\in K$ such that $g = kh$

Comment: Try $G = ({\mathbb Z},+)$, $\phi(n)=2n$.